# xpath help: find a div with a child button

Tags: xpath

Can I have a suggestion to find an xpath for the pods (boxes) on this page?
https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/sign/pricing/plans.html
Here is what I have, but it only finds 2 of them:

```
//div[@class="flex" and .//a[contains(., "Buy Now")]]
```

Comment: have you try this '//div[@class="flex" and .//a[contains(., "Buy Now") or 
    ...: contains(., "Buy now")]]?

Comment: Clever, @SamsulIslam, but in Chrome dev tools, Elements tab, Ctrl+F, no, it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer:

```
//div[@class="flex" and .//a[contains(@class, "spectrum-Button")]]

or

(//div[@class="flex" and .//a[contains(@class, "spectrum-Button")]])[index]

   where index = 1, 2, or 3
```